# RSpec not doing reload or not saving object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm facing a problem with rspec.

This is my test code:

```
describe "email address with mixed case" do
  let(:mixed_case_email) { "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM" }

  it "should be saved as all lower-case" do
    @user2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: 'aaaa@aaa.com')

    @user2.email = mixed_case_email
    p @user2.email
    p @user2.save!
    p @user2.email
    p @user2.reload.email
    expect(@user2.reload.email).to eq mixed_case_email.downcase
  end
end
```

My terminal outputs:

```
"Foo@ExAMPle.CoM"
true
"aaaa@aaa.com"
"aaaa@aaa.com"
```

My user model:

```
#encoding: UTF-8
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
     :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable,
     :timeoutable, :omniauthable

  before_validation { self.email.downcase! if self.email }

  validates :email, presence: true, length: {:maximum => 60}

end
```

Looks like reload or save are not working. Don't know what I can do. Have this same test in other projects but without devise. Can it be the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is devise :)

Devise does not allow you to change `email` without confirmation. When you set another email devise saves it in `unconfirmed_email`, generates `confirmation_token` and sends a email to confirm it. So you have a conflict with gem devise functionality.

Not sure but I think you can check that `unconfirmed_email` is downcased after saving

Comment: That's exactly what I'll do. Thank you!